# Is there a way to log files that are copied from an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a way to log when data is copied from my S3 bucket.  Most importantly, which file(s) were copied and when. If I had my way, I'd like by who and where but I don't want to get ahead of myself.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

- [Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/server-access-logging.html) provides detailed records for the requests that are made to an S3 bucket
- [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) captures a subset of API calls for Amazon S3 as events, including calls from the Amazon S3 console and from code calls to the Amazon S3 APIs